# rfc822 email content inside the subject

Tags: php, email, rfc822

using Gmail API with PHP and curl, I have that :

```
$message = "To: hisemail@domain.com\r\nFrom: myemail@domain.com\r\nSubject: thesubject\r\n The message";
$ch = curl_init('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Authorization: Bearer ".$access_token, 
    'Accept: application/json', 
    'Content-Type: message/rfc822'  
)); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $message);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

It is working very well, the email arrives with the subject. BUT only the subject, not the content ("The message").
Does someone know where the content is gone ? How could I do not changing all that script ?
Thank you very much

Comment: I think it is rfc2822 no?

Comment: Dear Roukoumoute, I changed from rfc822 to rfc2822 and I have the content inside the subject. So I receive an email with content and subject in the subject and no content